# CakePHP : Read values of a radio form

Tags: forms, cakephp, model-view-controller, save, cakephp-3.0

I'd like to read the values of a form I'm trying to use :

```
<!-- File: src/Template/Users/edit.ctp -->
<?php
    echo '<p>Question 1 text</p>';
    echo $this->Form->radio(
    'answer_1',
    [
    ['value' => 'true', 'text' => 'Radio 1 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 2 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 3 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 4 text'],
    ]
    );

    echo '<p>Question 2 text</p>';
    echo $this->Form->radio(
    'answer_2',[
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 1 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 2 text'],
    ['value' => 'true', 'text' => 'Radio 3 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 4 text'],
    ]
    );

    echo '<p>Question 3 text</p>';
    echo $this->Form->radio(
    'answer_3',[
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 1 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 2 text'],
    ['value' => 'false', 'text' => 'Radio 3 text'],
    ['value' => 'true', 'text' => 'Radio 4 text'],
    ]
    );

echo $this->Form->button(__("Save"));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

I would like in my edit function to read the values of the submitted radios, in order to calculate a score for each "true". Do you know how to do it in my controller ? Neither the questions nor the answers are stored in DB, they're hard-coded in the view.

Bonus point : I'd like to save a specific answer of the form in DB, in that possible ? For example, a bonus question :

```
echo '<p>Bonus question text</p>';
echo $this->Form->control('bonus_answer');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find how to get request data [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)

**3.0 - 3.3**

What you're looking for is

```
$this->request->data('answer_1');
$this->request->data('answer_2');
$this->request->data('answer_3');
```

**AS OF 3.4**

The use of `$this->request->data()` has been deprecated.

What you're looking for is

```
$this->request->getData('answer_1');
$this->request->getData('answer_2');
$this->request->getData('answer_3');
```

The "name" of the inputs is the first param of the function, `$this->Form->control('INPUTNAME');`